# Is it a valid transaction where my transactional method just completes the db.put() operation?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

I had tried to make my entire POST method transactional, but was unable to because it called other methods and was therefore nested.  So what I've done is created a transactional method just to complete the db.put() of my entity.

```
def post(self):
    myobj = db.get(key)
    myobj.property = x + 1
    second_method()
    my_txn(my_obj)

@db.transactional
def my_txn(obj):
    db.put(obj)
```

Is this a valid way to create a transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No I don't think it has any use regarding the concept of TA.

Something like this:

```
def post(self):
    second_method()
    my_txn(key)

@db.transactional
def my_txn(key):
    myobj = db.get(key)
    myobj.property = x + 1
    db.put(obj)
```

You should use transactions in order to ensure that the read(get) and write(put) are consistent.

In this way you know that when you are getting the entity and until you write the entity if anything has changed in the meanwhile will abort this TA and have a retry (default 3).

In your way of using it the get is outside the transaction thus making the transaction useless

Comment: Thanks!  I'll have to break up my POST into methods that aren't nested.

Comment: Can I ask a followup?  Would this work to build off your suggestion, what if I db.get() the entity in the post method manipulate it and then send it to the transaction just to be copied after getting it again by key in the transaction method.

Comment: @DanielYoung if the calculations are indepotent then probably yes. 
If though you depend on fresh values then no. Eg. If you are increasing a counter, then it's a bad idea. But if you are md5 sum the entity and then passing the result along with the key to the transaction, (the key does not change) then yes this will work.

Comment: Great - I can try to run it this way // method1: x = db.get(obj); modify x,  method2(x.key, x), where method2 is transactional calls x by key and assigns the new value.

Comment: @DanielYoung as long as no other request can alter the x then yes

Comment: I figure that it seems like I have to `db.get()` it out side the tranactional method to acquire the key regardless.

Comment: @DanielYoung can you paste what you want to achieve with a new question and mention the link here so I can have a better look. Paste exactly what calculations you want to achieve and how your structure of handler looks and I ll do my best to clear things out.

Comment: I've tried to rephrase it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813897/will-this-transaction-method-work